# Redirect image url to another page using .htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect this url

```
http://192.168.1.101/project/test/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Sunset.jpg
```

to this with main url as following.

```
http://192.168.1.101/project/test/wordpress/redirect.php?file=http://192.168.1.101/project/test/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Sunset.jpg
```

If url contain extension like .jpg, .png, .jpeg, .bmp, .png then move all it to redirect.php with file name like.

```
http://192.168.1.101/project/test/wordpress/redirect.php?file=imagefile
```

My current .htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/test/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/test/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Please Help Me..

Answer (score 1):

Insert this line just after `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/.+?\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ redirect.php?file=http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=302,L,NC]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Does this URL work in browser: `http://192.168.1.101/project/test/wordpress/redirect.php?file=imagefile` ?

Comment: This worked well for me to view live site images while working on a local dev site without having to download the entire /uploads/ directory.